# How use syntax on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pgadmin

I user of pgadmin... I have a problem with SQL Server syntax for spatial joins.

I need this query on SQL Server:

```
select * 
from table a, table b
where st_within (st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
```

or

```
update table a 
set x = b.x
from table b
where st_within (st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
```

Comment: Hi there, could you tell us what you want to do?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You can try, I don't have too much experience with geometry:    
    `select * 
    from a join b ON a.geom.STCentroid().STWithin(b.geom) = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you might need something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON a.geom.STCentroid().STWithin( b.geom) = 1;
```

That can be later converted into an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE a 
SET x = b.x
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON a.geom.STCentroid().STWithin( b.geom) = 1;
```

You can find all the information on [MS Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/ogc-methods-on-geometry-instances)